# bison: extra operand curl. How to fix this?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I decided try to create my own Cyanogenmod build. My phone is a Nexus 5. But the first command in the guide failed.

Ubuntu says- `bison: extra operand ‘curl’`

Command was this:

```
bison build-essential curl flex git gnupg gperf libesd0-dev liblz4-tool libncurses5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libxml2 libxml2-utils lzop maven openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre pngcrush schedtool squashfs-tools xsltproc zip zlib1g-dev
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command calls `bison` which doesn't take more than one operand.

I guess your goal was to install `bison`, `build-essential`, `curl` etc.

You forgot `apt-get install` in front:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bison build-essential curl flex git gnupg gperf libesd0-dev liblz4-tool libncurses5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libxml2 libxml2-utils lzop maven openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre pngcrush schedtool squashfs-tools xsltproc zip zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: @Aachman Happens. Since my answer solved your problem, I ask you to accept it by clicking on the check-mark.